# email signature format for outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have made an email signature to be used for outlook, but when it is sent in the email, the format is changing.  The spaces between each section increase.  How do I code this to ensure that the format does not change?

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="container" style="margin:0;background:#fff;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:inherit;width:580px; box-style: borderbox; position: relative;">
     <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
        <p style=" color: #00b3b3; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; padding: 0;">Delia Bellaby</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><img src="https://s19.postimg.org/95hmbn6ar/design_Make_Logo.jpg"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><p style="color: #00b3b3; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold">Architect</p></td> 
 </tr>

  <tr>
      <td><p style="color: #9C9E9E; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mobile: 022 362 6916 </p></td>  
  </tr> 


   <tr>
      <td><p style="text-align: left; color: #9C9E9E; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; border-top: 2px solid #00b3b3; padding-top: 10px; "><strong style="color:#00b3b3;">website:</strong> <a href="http://www.designmake.co.nz" style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C9E9E;">http://www.designmake.co.nz</a><br><strong style="color:#00b3b3;">email:</strong> delia@designmake.co.nz</p></td>  
  </tr> 

  <tr>
    <td>
        <span style="text-align: left; color: #00b3b3; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; ">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/designmakearchitects/"><img style="color: #3399ff; height: 30px; width: 30px;" src="https://s19.postimg.org/6begy7bub/Facebook-_Home-_Logo.png"></a></span>
    </td>   
  </tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to create the same signature in the Outlook UI and see how it is saved?

Comment: Yes, the formatting was worse in the outlook UI, so I was asked to try and make a HTML signature for them.  I have just read about after pasting the signature in, clicking the paste icon and selecting the HTML paste icon, so I am hoping that this solves the issues.  Thank you for taking the time to help.